# Issue with sql where clause when using datetime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

Can anyone help me out with this query i m trying to execute,

```
 static public DataTable GetAllCustomers()
{
    string sql = "Select * from [project] where [condition] = 0 AND [Time] < '" + DateTime.Now + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ConnectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

It returns nothing

Any ideas where i am getting the query wrong.

Comment: Everytime you use the `+` operator when building a SQL query very bad things will happen.

Comment: What format is your `datetime.now()` returning?

Comment: @Darin ,i know abt sql injection , will use the parameters for it .JK   the time field in db is datetime

Comment: @JNK, depends on the cultural settings of the application I believe unless specified. Mr A, you don't need to use parameters at all for this example, see both answers below :)

Comment: Debugging 101: `console.writeline(sql);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting DateTime's into SQL Strings is a recipe for disaster thanks to formatting and locations.  Change your sql line to:

```
string sql = "Select * from [project] where [condition] = 0 AND [Time] < GetDate()";
```

This will use the servers own current date time in whatever format it is expecting.

If you absolutely need to do things client side then use SqlCommand and instead of adding DateTime as a string put a "Time < @" and then add the DateTime as a command parameter. That will avoid formatting problems at least.

Answer (score 2):

Did you know SQL server has a built in time function. Try this:

```
string sql = "Select * from [project] where [condition] = 0 AND [Time] < GETDATE()";
```

or if you want date in UTC do this:

```
string sql = "Select * from [project] where [condition] = 0 AND [Time] < GETUTCDATE()";
```

This way you do not have any string concatinations in code.

Could you answer the following:

1. Which part is coming back nothing?
2. Is `[Time]` a `DATETIME` data type or similar (ie: not text)